# Django: cannot redirect to UpdateView after item is deleted

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a view just for deleting `ListItems` that correspond to a `List` objects, through a `ForeignKey`.

I can successfully delete the ListItem, but I cannot redirect to the original template.

```
def full_remove_listitem(request, listitem_id):
    list_item = ListItem.objects.get(id=listitem_id)
    list_item.delete()
    lista_id = list_item.lista.id
    return redirect('lists:list_details lista_id')
```

I get:

> **NoReverseMatch at /listas/borrar-producto-de-lista/29/**
>       Reverse for 'list_details lista_id' not found. 'list_details lista_id' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

I've also tried:

```
return reverse('lists:list_details', kwargs={'lista_id': lista_id})
```

But I get:

> AttributeError at /listas/borrar-producto-de-lista/30/ 'str' object
>   has no attribute 'get'

**Urls.py:**

```
app_name = "lists"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.ListFormView.as_view(), name='my_lists'),
    path('agregar-producto/', views.add_product_to_list, name='add_product_to_list'),
    path('mis-listas/', views.update_lists_count, name='update_lists_count'),
    path('lista-detalles/<int:lista_id>/', views.ListDetailsFormView.as_view(), name='list_details'),
    path('escuelas-csv/', views.schools_upload, name="schools_upload"),
    path('borrar-producto-de-lista/<int:listitem_id>/', views.full_remove_listitem, name='full_remove_listitem'),
    path('borrar-lista/<int:lista_id>/', views.full_remove_list, name='full_remove_list'),
    path('borrar-escuela/<int:school_id>/', views.full_remove_school, name='full_remove_school'),
]
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    {% for list_item in list_items %}
        {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:3 and not forloop.first %}<div class="w-100"></div>{% endif %}
        <div class="card margin-right3" style="width: 14rem;">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">{{ list_item.product.short_name }}</h5>
              <p class="card-title">$ {{ list_item.product.price }}</p>
              <p class="card-text">{{ list_item.description }}</p>
              <a href="{% url 'lists:full_remove_listitem' list_item.id %}" class="custom_icon"><i
                class="fas fa-trash-alt custom_icon"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div> 
    {% endfor %}
```

**views.py:** View where I want to redirect:

```
class ListDetailsFormView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = List
    form_class = ListForm
    context_object_name = 'lista'
    pk_url_kwarg  = 'lista_id'
    template_name = "scolarte/listas/lista-detalles.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        list_items = ListItem.objects.filter(lista=self.object)
        context['list_items'] = list_items
        list_total = 0
        for list_item in list_items:
            list_total += Decimal(list_item.sub_total())
        context['list_total'] = list_total
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        #form.instance.name = self.request.name
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('lists:list_details', kwargs={'lista_id': self.object.pk})
```

**models.py:**

```
class ListItem(models.Model):
    lista = models.ForeignKey(List, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, default='')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    step_two_complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def sub_total(self):
        return int(self.product.price)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the second example in the [`redirect()` documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#examples) you'll see that the first argument should be the view name then the id can be passed as a keyword argument.

```
def full_remove_listitem(request, listitem_id):
    list_item = ListItem.objects.get(id=listitem_id)
    list_item.delete()
    lista_id = list_item.lista.id
    return redirect('lists:list_details', lista_id=lista_id)
```

Comment: Do you mean example 2? `def my_view(request):
    ...
    return redirect('some-view-name', foo='bar')` 

It is not clear to me from the docs.

Comment: @OmarGonzales yes, my mistake

Comment: Interesting, because as you can see in my question, I was already sending a keyword argument like: `return reverse('lists:list_details', kwargs={'lista_id': lista_id})`.

Comment: `reverse()` returns a string, if you wrapped `redirect()` around it then it would work